# Select from two sub-queries, with join on another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two queries pulling from three tables:

```
t1 -sites
t2 - blues
t3 - reds
```

query1 -

```
SELECT s.site_name b.year b.value 
FROM sites s, blues b 
WHERE s.id = b.site_id AND s.site_name ='site1'
```

returning the following (eg.)

```
| site_name  |  year  |  blues  |
| site1      |  2012  |   23.6  | 
| site1      |  2011  |   19.1  |
| site1      |  2010  |   10.2  |
| site1      |  2009  |   25.8  | 
| site1      |  2008  |   14.0  |
```

query 2

```
SELECT s.site_name r.year r.value 
FROM sites s, reds r 
WHERE s.id = r.site_id 
AND s.site_name ='site1'
```

returning:

```
| site_name  |  year  |    reds  |
| site1      |  2012  |     14.0 | 
| site1      |  2010  |     11.0 |
| site1      |  2009  |     18.9 |
```

I eventually want this:

```
| site_name  |  year  |  blues  |  reds  |
| site1      |  2012  |   23.6  |   14.0 | 
| site1      |  2011  |   19.1  |        |
| site1      |  2010  |   10.2  |   11.0 |
| site1      |  2009  |   25.8  |   18.9 | 
| site1      |  2008  |   14.0  |        |
```

Which basically amounts to all the records in both the blues and reds table for a site, matched on years even when one of the tables does not have a record for that year.

Many thanks to @vkp for pointing me in the right direction: CTEs to the rescue.

Here is the tested query

```
WITH x AS (SELECT s.site_name AS name, b.year AS yr1, b.value AS blue_val
    FROM public.sites s JOIN public.blues b 
    ON  s.id = b.site_id
    WHERE s.site_name = 'Site1'
    ), y AS (SELECT s.site_name, r.year AS yr2, r.value AS red_val
    FROM public.stations s JOIN public.reds r 
    ON  s.id = r.site_id
    WHERE s.site_name = 'Site1'
    )
    SELECT x.name, x.yr1, x.blue_val, y.red_val
    FROM x LEFT JOIN y ON x.yr1 = y.yr2
```

Comment: You should really get used to explicit `JOIN`s rather than implicit joins in the where clause

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT s.site_name, b.year, b.value as blues, r.value as reds
FROM sites s right join blues b on s.id = b.site_id
right join reds r on s.id = r.site_id and b.year = r.year
where s.site_name ='site1'
```

Updated query with CTE:

```
with x as (SELECT s.site_name, b.year, b.value as blues
    FROM sites s join blues b on s.id = b.site_id
    where s.site_name ='site1') 
    , y as (SELECT s.site_name, r.year, r.value as blues
    FROM sites s join reds r on s.id = r.site_id
    where s.site_name ='site1')
    ,yrs as (select year from x union select year from y)
    select 
    case when x.site_name is not null then x.site_name 
    else y.site_name end as site_name
    , yrs.year, x.value as blue_val, y.value as red_val
    from yrs left join x on x.year = yrs.year
    left join y on y.year = yrs.year
```

Comment: Thanks for the response:  Neither solution provides the desired result: the year column appears in both the reds and blues table.  Using either response (@vkp, @ImCrimson) results in multiple (duplicate) records of blues. The number of duplicates is equal to the number of matching site records in the reds table: using the original example it would yield three records for site one, one for each value in the reds table.

Comment: modified to join on `year` as well. try this

Comment: thanks for the immediate response:  getting closer, however this only displays the records in years where both red and blue have data; it does not display records for blues where records for reds does not exist (years 2011 and 2008 in the original example).

Comment: modified to `RIGHT JOIN` on `reds` and `blues` table as the `year` information is being fetched from those.

Comment: No, there is not, reds and blues actually corresponded to different measurements (or derived data) each year. what I eventually want to be able to compare years that have (or do not have) both data and then fill in missing data in the reds table with estimated values from a regression.

Comment: left or right joins make no difference; same record set returned (equating to  years where only both blues and reds have a record).  I was thinking you would return two independent sets (one for all the blues for a site, and one for all the reds) and then some how join the queries?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.site_name b.year b.value r.value
FROM sites s
INNER JOIN blues b ON s.id = b.site_id AND s.site_name ='site1'
INNER JOIN reds r ON s.id = r.site_id AND s.site_name ='site1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me if the syntax isn't quite right - I'm not as familiar with Postgresql.

If you can nest queries:

```
SELECT
  s.site_name,
  i.year,
  i.blues,
  i.reds
FROM
  #sites AS s,
  (
    SELECT
      COALESCE( b.site_id, r.site_id ) AS site_id,
      COALESCE( b.year, r.year ) AS year,
      b.value AS blues,
      r.value AS reds
    FROM
      #blues AS b
      FULL OUTER JOIN #reds AS r
        ON r.year = b.year AND r.site_id = b.site_id
  ) AS i
WHERE
  s.site_name = 'site1' AND
  i.site_id = s.site_id
```

If you can't, use a UNION to separate the join types where you're collecting sets where both blue and red exist for the year, where only blue exists for the year and where only red exists for the year:

```
SELECT
  s.site_id,
  b.year AS year,
  b.value AS blues,
  r.value AS reds
FROM
  #sites s
  INNER JOIN #blues b
    ON b.site_id = s.site_id
  INNER JOIN #reds r
    ON r.site_id = s.site_id AND
       r.year = b.year
WHERE
  s.site_name = 'site1'
UNION
SELECT
  s.site_id,
  b.year AS year,
  b.value AS blues,
  null AS reds
FROM
  #sites s
  INNER JOIN #blues b
    ON b.site_id = s.site_id
WHERE
  s.site_name = 'site1' AND
  b.year NOT IN ( SELECT year FROM #reds WHERE #reds.site_id = s.site_id )
UNION
SELECT
  s.site_id,
  r.year AS year,
  null AS blues,
  r.value AS reds
FROM
  #sites s
  INNER JOIN #reds r
    ON r.site_id = s.site_id
WHERE
  s.site_name = 'site1' AND
  r.year NOT IN ( SELECT year FROM #blues WHERE #blues.site_id = s.site_id )
```